# How to import data to a table with 14 columns via BCP if my data file has less than 13 delimiters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

Sorry for the extremely awkward wording in that question. I'll explain.

I have a table with 14 columns in which i'm trying to import data to via BCP. My data comes from a text file. This text file is TAB delimited. Logically there should be 13 delimiters for 14 cells of data in a row. My data is inconsistent and doesn't have delimiters if the values at the end are null. This means that some rows of data only have 10 delimiters. This causes my data to "wrap around" when it is imported. The first cell of data in my text file is being put in the 10th column of the row prior to it. It should be the first cell in its own new row.

The thing is every single row in the text file ends in with "CRLF" which is used by default in BCP.

Is there a way to tell BCP to fill in all 14 columns before moving on to the next row? Or will i have to re format my data file every time i import (not ideal).

Here is my BCP command:

```
 bcp testdb.dbo.MACARP in C:\Users\sysbrady\Desktop\MyData.txt /c /T /t "\t" /E -S WSTVDISTD023\SQLEXPRESS
```

Comment: Is it because of NULL values that it is not extending out all 14 feilds?

Comment: @Dillon I think so. If cells 13 and 14 for a particular row don't exist then the file will not create the delimiters to reach that far. It is odd because if cell 2 is null and cell 3 is not, it will add a delimiter there.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83741/how-to-import-data-to-a-table-with-14-columns-via-bcp-if-my-data-file-has-less-t

Comment: @Ryan Uh, yeah, thanks, I do know how to read. Don't post the same question to multiple Stack Exchange sites, ok?

Comment: @AaronBertrand oops sorry. I didnt realize thats why you were linking that. You are right, i am a dummy.

Comment: i am not familiar with BCP but would it be possible to change the script to use COALESCE to repalce a NULL with a unique identifier like a string that says "NULL" or zero?

Comment: If you open the file in excel, and save it, are the missing columns created, and can BCP import the file then?

Answer (score 2):

> "Is there a way to tell BCP to fill in all 14 columns before moving on to the next row?"

When you say "fill in", do you mean you want BCP to keep the null values present in your text file?  The -k qualifier tells BCP to keep the nulls (make sure the column in your table allows nulls).  See link below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187887.aspx

> "The thing is every single row in the text file ends in with "CRLF" which is used by default in BCP."

This is unclear - could you post an image?  Unsure of whether you have phrased this as a problem, or a feature you want to retain.